# How to connect my server with my ember cli App

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

my server is working on the port :3000  and i am using node, express on server side and this is working fine while using curl or REST client.

ember cli server is working on port :4200

I added this code on environment.js for connecting server to client.

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
              'default-src': "'none'",
              'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'",
              'font-src': "'self'",
              'connect-src': "'self' http://localhost:3000",
              'img-src': "'self'",
              'report-uri':"'localhost'",
              'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
              'frame-src': "'none'"
     }
```

and my application adapter code is:

```
import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    "host": "http://localhost:3000",
    "namespace": "api"
});
```

running my ember server on this way 
**ember server --proxy http://127.0.0.1:3000** 
on  controller i use ajax call :

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/blog',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: param,
                    processData: false,
                    success :
              });
```

it getting an error: 
**POST http://localhost:4200/blog 500 (Internal Server Error)**

i have done all these but i don't know  why it's not working.
please help me if you have any idea for that .

Comment: Have you checked your server error logs? The HTTP status code indicates that it's something inside the server that's triggering an error.

Comment: @lock Thanks brother. now its working fine

Comment: yah the error is no server side not on client.

Comment: but can i ask one question?
is it a good way to do (connecting ember with server)?

Comment: Yup, it sounds fine to me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between two ways to connect to your API:

**Proxy**

You can use the `--proxy` option of `ember-cli` to proxy all requests made to your ember development server that are not handled by ember to your backend.

This is a good way to do this because from the view of your application and browser your backend and your application are on the same host.

If you do so you should *not* specify the `host` on your adapter or add your backend to your CSP configuration.

However you can do this only if in production you serve your ember application from your backend.

**`CORS`**

The other way to connect to your backend is to make your requests directly to another origin. However this will be `CORS` requests so they need additional configuration on your backend!

If you want to directly fetch data from a different origin, in browser land your server there needs to deliver additional `HTTP` headers (`CORS` Headers).

However you should do this *only* do this if you will not deliver your frontend from your backend server in production.

If you want to use `CORS` you should *not* specify the `--proxy` flag when you run `ember serve`, but specify the `host` and configure your CSP correctly.

---

I also mentioned that you missed a `=` in your `ember serve` call.

Its not `ember server --proxy http://127.0.0.1:3000` but `ember server --proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3000`!

Generally if you do `ember serve --proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3000` then a HTTP AJAX GET call to `http://localhost:4200/blog` should return the same as `http://127.0.0.1:3000/blog`.

To test this I recommend you to use a HTTP development client like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm).

I assume you get also a HTTP 500 on `http://127.0.0.1:3000/blog`. Then something is wrong on your backend. Maybe the correct URI is `http://127.0.0.1:3000/blogs`? that would be embers default.

If you do a call directly to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/blogs` from your ember application this will however always result in an error if you don't deliver the `CORS` headers.

Comment: This was really helpful fro me .

Comment: But i don't no how to use Proxy server on same port . if you have have any link for developing server on same port then please let me known it's really helpul from me.

Comment: @niteshsingh what exactly do you mean with same port? why would you do this?

Comment: Now my server is working on port 3000 and ember cli  is working in 4200    is there any idea to work server and client in same port.

Comment: Well, thats the entire thing about the proxy right? that you don't have to run them on the same port. You proxy from your fronted to your backend so from your fronted it behaves like its on the same port/origin even if its not, because you can't run two servers on the same origin. And later for production deliver your build ember app with your backend.

Comment: yes it's not need to me now   but i just need to know is there any whey to do this?

Comment: @niteshsingh For the same host you can't start service with same port.